# What would be the impact on web portal when developed using .net framework 3.5 or developed using .net framework 4.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

since few years we are using .net framework 3.5 for developing web application but now we are deciding to switch on .net framework 4.5.1 for performance

Can any one describe me a real time scenario of performance impact on web application if we use .net framework 4.5.1 instead of 3.5

Also Core features difference between 3.5 & 4.5 in term of development

i am also curious on following

1. if i used mvc over web form
2. if i used view engine razor over asp view engine

does it make any impact on performance..??

Any help would be appreciated..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Performance of .NET 3.5 vs 4.0

DotNetPearls made some benchmarks on if there were any [performance gains moving from 3.5 to 4.0](http://www.dotnetperls.com/net-35-net-40-benchmark) and this was their assessment

> "Equivalent programs compiled and executed using the .NET 4.0 Framework may execute >faster than those based on .NET 3.5 SP1. Your software will probably get an easy >performance boost if you move it to a newer Framework version." - [DotNetPearls](http://www.dotnetperls.com/net-35-net-40-benchmark)

### What is news in .Net Framework 4, 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2

Here you can find what is new in the .Net Framework 4, 4.5, 4.5.1 and 4.5.2.

[What is New in the .NET Framework 4](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[What's New in the .NET Framework 4.5, 4.5.1, and 4.5.2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Edit to address your updated question..

### Regarding performance and patterns

there is no practical way to compare performance since you will will use very different patterns to code in one versus the other.

both are built on the asp.net framework, and have the same request events. WebForms adds life cycle events. MVC controllers use model binding. In WebForms controls lookup their values via a dictionary lookup, MVC model binding is done via reflection. WebForms were more efficient when I last tried to benchmark them, but require building the whole control tree. the more controls, the more overhead. WebForm databinding also uses refection, so if you use WebForm databinding, then you lose its performance edge.

I believe that razor views are still slower than WebForms views, but I would still use razor.

But looking at it from a bigger picture not all the code that is the same, database, entities, business rules, session management, etc. except for the simplest of applications, this will be the bottleneck, not the html rendering engine.

Something more to consider is the availability of developers in your area that know one technology over the other, costs and architecture could be greatly impacted if you have a hard time finding good developers to develop and maintain the application.

[Marla Sukesh](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Membership/View.aspx?mid=5468850) at Codeproject have made a [comparison between MVC and WebForms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/528117/WebForms-vs-MVC) that might be helpful as well.

Comment: what if i use mvc structure and razor view engine, does it improve my site performance..!!

Comment: i am not clear on mvc and webform , you mean to say that mvc would improve performance as web forms have more controls and overhead..

Comment: I would say that unless you have the best coders in the world available it will make no difference in terms of speed and you should go with the one that your developers are most familiar with - that said I would always use MVC since I find it to be the technology that is advancing faster, will have the most developers and I find it easier to develop, debug and test

Comment: Web forms has the additional overhead of view state, among other things so mvc might make a difference..

Comment: Like I said I would go with MVC.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56406/discussion-between-karl-henrik-and-abbas-galiyakot).

Answer (score 0):

For MVC and Web forms,

I prefer MVC, as web forms has page life cycle. Also it reduces page HTML as it has no viewstate ovehead.